# Получить содержимое подгруженного поля

Tags: ajax, javascript

Допустим, я подгрузил поле через аякс и вставил его в документ через html(), после я его изменил, как мне получить новое значение данного поля? При вызове его значения выдает undefined

```
function set() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'blablabla',
            success: function(res) { 
                            $('#section').html(res);
            }
        });
}   
function get() {
    var input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    alert(input);
}
```

Ну а это само поле.

```
<input type="text" id="input" value="" onchange="get()">
```

Comment: >> после я его изменил

в каком смысле "изменил"? Заполнил значение поля вручную или что?

Comment: Да, заполнил значение поля вручную.

Comment: @rimlin, попробуйте для начала так: >><input type="text" id="input" value=""> <input type="button" onclick="get()" value="Получить значение">

Comment: undefined по прежнему

Comment: @rimlin, попробуйте так: var input = $('#input').val();

Comment: так же пробовал, выдает саму функцию jquery

Comment: @rimlin, может проблема в название переменной... Попробуйте например inputq, а не input.

Comment: Да по всякому уже их называл - результат undefined :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Комменты отключились. Напишу тут.

Попробуйте так:

```
var input = $('#section').find('#input').val();
```

Comment: вопрос решил, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

делегируйте событие "onchange" с помощь `.on()`

```
$('body').on('change', 'input'/*ваш селектор*/, function(){
    alert(this.value);
});
```

[пруф](http://jsfiddle.net/kRKcm/)

- [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)